# Could not find or load main class "Name" - hadoop(windows)

Tags: hadoop

I am encountering this error while executing the command 
hdfs -version.
I tried changing the user name from  hadoop-env.cmd like "set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=" " but still the same problem.

Comment: should be hadoop version

Comment: Make sure you install Hadoop and Java to a path without spaces